# Amd Cpu Or Apu Under 10k

Tags: processor, android, video-editing, ryzen

I'm going to build a pc for video editing, android studio and gaming at 1080p in future by adding gtx 1650 super but am confused between 3 processors

1. Ryzen 5 1600 at 8200 Rs
2. Ryzen 5 3500 at 10000 Rs
3. Ryzen 5 2400G at 9700 Rs

Which of them will be suitable for my needs i will not able to buy gpu till three month after this build so getting worry if i go for 1600 or 3500 without gpu how it will boot up but if i go with Apu i have to compromise with cores and threads which leads to more time in export videos at 1080p and 4k so if there is any solution please let me know.

Comment: Newsflash: https://www.pcworld.com/article/3539431/amds-b550-motherboards-will-bring-pcie-4-0-to-the-masses-99-ryzen-3-cpu-in-tow.html

Comment: It means Ryzen 3 3100 and 3100X had better single core performance i saw many YouTube videos and it performs so well in some cases outperform intel i7 7700K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can buy the GTX1650, ignore the

R5 2400G = 4 cores 3.6 GHz base 3.9 GHz boost clock RX11 Vega graphics 
for the card is far superior to onboard graphics.

So, it's a battle for your budget, when it's time to buy, of the the

R5 1600 = 6 cores 3.2 GHz base 3.6 GHz boost clock

vs.

R5 3600 = 6 cores 3.6 GHz base 4.2 GHz boost clock (3500 discontinued)

plus [whatever else AMD comes out with](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3539431/amds-b550-motherboards-will-bring-pcie-4-0-to-the-masses-99-ryzen-3-cpu-in-tow.html).

Answer (score -1):

Without an APU, you won't be able to use this PC. Some Ryzen CPUs don't have integrated graphics, and neither do the motherboards for this platform; others (such as the Ryzen 5 3400G) do. With that in mind, you have three options:
1) buy an APU like the 2400G, and live with the lower multi-threaded performance.
2) Buy a Ryzen CPU and try to source a scrap-level graphics card (aka the cheapest used PCIe graphics card you can find) just to be able to use the PC until the graphics card arrives.
3) don't use the PC until you can afford a GPU. Which is by far the worst option. If you can't use the PC now, you might as well delay the purchase until you can afford all the parts. PC parts tend to get cheaper over time, and new parts become available.

Comment: Is msi gt 710 2gb enough to boot up and able to use adobe premiere pro ? Then the next thing is r5 1600 zen 1 has 6 cores and 12 threads where r5 3500 zen 3 has 6 cores and 6 threads which of them seems perform better in editing and emulator stuff

Comment: @KirandeepMaan: a GT 710 would be good enough. However, I really want to emphasize how overpriced this graphics card is. So by all means, don't buy it new. The second question about which CPU to buy might be better suited for a new question entirely. It's a tough call, and depends on which software exactly you use, and how you use it.

Comment: @K7AAY: I don't think that I left much ambiguity between my usage of these terms. The first 2 sentences clearly distinguish Ryzen APUs from Ryzen CPUs by their defining feature: integrated graphics. Or do you prefer a term like non-APU? A pedant might argue that this stands for anything that's not an APU. Like boats, refrigerators and whatnot ;)

Comment: I'm going to use Android Studio, Adobe Photoshop And Adobe Premiere Pro actually i don't know that more single performance matters in them or more multi threads helps and I'm getting used gt 710 at 18$ which isn't much till i get new gpu then shift this to old PC and now question is between r5 1600 or r5 3500 is it worth paying extra bucks for r5 3500 over r3 1600 or there was any other option available under 10000 Rs Indian.

Comment: 18$ is a fair price for that GPU. I'm not familiar with the hardware market in India. But from a pure performance standpoint at regular prices, you might want to consider the Ryzen 1600 AF. It's a Ryzen 5 1600, manufactured in a smaller process. In terms of performance, it is very similar to a Ryzen 5 2600, and it should be cheaper. This would be my recommendation over the Ryzen 5 3500.

Comment: Yes this also come into my mind and have offer to buy Af variant just at just 8.2k but i would like to know if it was AF model Its model code is YD1600BBAFBOX Is it stock or af model

Comment: The old Ryzen 5 1600 (boxed version) has the model number YD1600BBAEBOX. The newer 12nm Ryzen 5 1600 "AF" (boxed version) has the model number YD1600BBAFBOX. So you should be good.